# why relation cannot be used here?

Tags: word-choice

The study found a strong relationship between a lack of friends and sibling rivalry.

In Cambridge book Vocabulary For IELTS by Pauline Cullen, Unit 1, the author said that the word "relationship" cannot be replaced with the word "relation", and I cannot understand why.  Could you provide explanation for this?

Comment: I would simply disagree. I *would* use relationship (or connection) in this case, however not for any reason other than I use it more than relation in situations such as these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the book you quote is wrong. ***Relation* can be used in that way. It is OED sense 2a of the noun**, which has plenty of 20th/21st century examples. (See below.)

However, it is far more common nowadays to use the term ***relationship*** when speaking in that sense. But whilst ***relation*** has been used since at least the 14th century, we don't see instances of ***relationship*** until the 18th. (See further example below).

Re ***relation***

2a. Examples exist from the 14th century but modern ones are:

> 1816   R. Jameson Treat. External Characters Minerals (ed. 2) 168
>   The nucleus increases on its part, always preserving the same relation
>   with the entire crystal.
>
> 1879   G. C. Harlan Eyesight ix. 131   The size and form of the desk,
>   and its relation to the seat, are not without their effect upon the
>   welfare of the eyes.
>
> 1922   D. Jones Outl. Eng. Phonetics (ed. 2) p. ii   By referring the
>   vowels of all languages to a set of Cardinal Vowels, the relations
>   between them are made clearer.
>
> 1939   J. B. Morton Bonfire of Weeds viii. 190   A rather highbrow
>   discussion..that has little relation to the average man's life or
>   activities.
>
> 1988   A. Phillips Winnicott i. 1   Darwin had examined living things
>   to explain their relation to each other.
>
> 2002   Statesman (India) (Nexis) 13 Apr.   It has not been easy..to
>   establish a relation between the incidence of cancer and a certain
>   level of exposure to asbestos.

Re ***relationship***

Note that the earliest example is from the eighteenth century.

1. The state or fact of being related; the way in which two things are connected; a connection, an association. Also: kinship.

> 1724   W. Stukeley Of Spleen 52   The suddenness thereof or slowness,
>   shall not incommode the œconomy of the parts and vessels, and their
>   mutual actions and relationship.
>
> 1773   O. Goldsmith She stoops to Conquer ii. 38   Ay, but I know what
>   sort of relation you want to make me though; but it won't do... I want
>   no nearer relationship.
>
> 1804   W. Mitford Inq. Princ. Harmony Lang. (ed. 2) 345   The Welsh
>   themselves have been fond of claiming this relationship [for their
>   language].
>
> 1880   S. Haughton Six Lect. Physical Geogr. 268   Teeth of a small
>   Marsupial, Microlestes,..which show a relationship to Myrmecobius.
>
> 1915   E. Sapir in T. McFeat Indians of N. Pacific Coast (1987) 37
>   Intermarriages would bring about intercrossings of all sorts, and in
>   course of time the more remote degrees of relationship would be
>   forgotten.
>
> 1974   Nature 8 Nov. 130/2   The presocratic belief that causal
>   relationships existed between natural phenomena.
>
> 2005   Mercury (Hobart) (Nexis) 19 Aug.   Work done in grade 10 bears
>   no relationship to work done in kindergarten.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing I wanted to write when I wrote my comment, I just couldn't think of anything to write beyond your *"Well the book you quote is wrong. Relation can be used in that way. It is OED sense 2a of the noun"*... which I classed as NAA on its own

Comment: @NickA Do you have access to the OED online, Nick? If you are a member of a local library in the UK you will probably find it is available FOC using your library-card login.

Comment: Only the public part (word definitions/phrases/origin), not the dated historical example, and I don't think I've been to a library in years except when I had to read from a book I couldn't afford or find online :)

Comment: @NickA Well you are clearly interested in the English Language, or you wouldn't be here. It shouldn't cost anything to join your local municipal library, and they will probably have a subscription to the OED (as well as a lot of exciting things besides). You would find access to the OED very useful when participating on this site.